# Is Simon's problem a good NP-intermediate candidate?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, quantum-computing

We know that $BPP \subseteq BQP$ but we have no proof $BPP \subset BQP$
(Though we have the proof that BQP $!=$ BPP with an oracle)

Since Simon's problem (as factoring) it's easily solvable by a quantum computer, and in exponential time complexity solvable by a classical computer, that's a hint of the separation between BQP and BPP and therefore this can be a pure NP problem. 
Am I right?

Comment: What research and self-study have you done?  There are lots of sources that talk about this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simon's problem is not a pure NP problem, for two reasons:

- It is an oracle problem.  We are given an oracle for some function $f$.  That's not something that you can do within the definition of a NP problem.
- It is a promise problem.  We are given the promise that $f$ will satisfy a particular property (it is two-to-one, and has a particular structure).  That too is not something you can do within the definition of a NP problem.

So Simon's problem is not a problem in the formal complexity class NP; it's just something different.  For the same reasons, it's not NP-intermediate, either.